# Problem setting an html attribute containing hyphens in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have defined a custom html attribute "data-something-something". In my view I use an Html extension method to create for instance a text box. One of the parameters is an anonymous `object HtmlAttributes`. I want to pass this value: `new { data-something-something = "value" }`. However, `data-something-something` is not recognized by .NET as a property name because of the hyphens.

I changed it to `dataSomethingSomething` for now, but I would like to define my custom attribute according to the HTML 5 standard (i.e. prefix it with 'data-').

I had a similar problem before when trying to do `new { class = "class-name"}` on the class property. For this case I found that I can prefix `class` with an '@' symbol to make it work (i.e. `new { @class = "class-name"}`). Because there is a solution for this scenario, I hoped that there might be a solution for my current problem (prefixing it with an '@' did not work).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try using underscores which should be automatically converted into dashes by the standard HTML helpers:

```
new { data_something_something = "value" }
```

Comment: Neato! I was hoping for something like this.

Comment: @Matthijs Wessels, are you using a custom HTML helper? If yes, please show your helper code and usage. This definitely works with the built-in helpers. Try it: `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Foo, new { data_something_something = "value" })`.

Comment: I only use built-in helpers. Already tried it and it worked :)